# A modern English word or phrase that basically would mean "slave"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am considering a dystopian sci-fi setting where the most of the people are basically, government slaves.

So I am looking for a good modern-sounding term for them that would not sound archaic, medieval, and would not imply them being privately owned, criminals or incarcerated.

So far I considered the following:

- Bio-equipment (sounds too harsh and de-humanizing)
- Mobilized worker and conscriptee (both imply temporary nature of the status, which I do not want)
- Element of order (again, de-humanizing)

Can anyone suggest other variants, that basically would mean a worker without rights?

So, basically, a word for a worker without rights but not owned by anyone.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably result in downvotes, but I'll give it a shot. How about **proletarian**? As per M-W, a **proletarian** is a member of the *proletariat*, defined as follows:

> *proletariat*: the laboring class, especially the class of industrial workers who lack their own means of production and hence sell their labor to live

I wouldn't call this a "modern English word", but it does meet your other requirements and could work in a sci-fi setting. At least it's not a made-up word.

Comment: 'prole' is the usual sci-fi term.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. Good to know! I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's **serf**, and it's synonyms:

> chattel
>       laborer
>       peon
>       servant
>       vassal
>       villain
>       villein
>       bondservant
>       bondsman/woman
>       chattel
>       drudge
>       peon
>       slave
>       thrall
>       vassal    articled servant
>       bondslave
>       chattel
>       servant
>   assistant
>       attendant
>       cleaning person
>       dependent
>       domestic
>       drudge
>       help
>       helper
>       hireling
>       live-in
>       menial
>       minion
>       retainer
>       server
>    captive
>       laborer
>       menial
>       peon
>       skivvy
>       subservient
>       toiler
>       victim
>       worker
>       workhorse